# How do I negate a property in Maven?

Tags: maven, plugins, boolean, maven-3

I have a property defined in a profile:

> <use.mysql.db>true</use.mysql.db>

Is there a way I can specify the inverse of this property in the "<skip>" section of one of my executions?

I want to say:

> <skip>!${use.mysql.db}</skip>